# Property as a Function Type in a Class

Tags: swift, function, types, properties

Given the following:

```
enum Output {
    case typeA, typeB
}    

class SomeClass {
    var outputFunc: (Int) -> () = methodA // error here

    var output: Output = .typeA {
        didSet {
            if output == .typeA {
                outputFunc = methodA
            }
            else {
                outputFunc = methodB
            }
        }
    }

    func methodA(val: Int) {/* do something */} 
    func methodB(val: Int) {/* do something */} 
}
```

Everything in the `didSet` compiles just fine, but where I declare `outputFunc` I get an error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(SomeClass) -> (Int) -> ()' to specified type '(Int) -> ()'

I'm not sure how to init this property. I've tried changing it to `self.methodA` but obviously `self` doesn't exists yet. If I change the type of `outputFunc` to `(SomeClass) -> (Int) -> ()` then the property compiles, but the `didSet` gives me the opposite error.

Comment: "I'm not sure how to init this property. I've tried changing it to `self.methodA` but obviously self doesn't exists yet.". Exactly! If you already understand that `self` doesn't exist at this point, then you should understand why you can't do `var outputFunc: (Int) -> () = methodA`. `methodA` and `self.methodA` are the same thing.

Comment: As @Sweeper says, you don't have `self` available yet, but you could change it to a `lazy` property if you're happy for it to be initialised on first use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message could be more descriptive, since the real error is indeed that you are trying to access `self` before it would be ready, because `outputFunc` is an instance property, while `methodA` is an instance method.

To resolve this issue, you can simply make `outputFunc` `lazy`.

```
lazy var outputFunc: (Int) -> () = methodA
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said

> but obviously self doesn't exists yet

You seem to understand that you can't access `self` until after all the properties have been initialised in the initialiser. Well, `methodA` and `self.methodA` are actually the same thing. The former is just short for the latter, because `self` is not needed normally when there is no ambiguity.

One solution is to initialise it in the initialiser, after initialising `outputFunc` to something else first:

```
init() {
    outputFunc = {_ in}
    outputFunc = methodA
}
```

Personally though, I really don't think there's any danger in allowing you to assign a method to a property when the class/struct is not properly initialised. This restriction prevents stuff like this from happening (contrived example):

```
class Foo {
    var foo = f() // foo's value should be the return value of f...
    func f() -> Int {
        print(foo) // but to execute f, we need the value of foo...
        return foo + 1 // so what is the value of foo?
    }
}
```

But since you are not actually calling `methodA`, I don't see how this assignment can cause problems. My guess is that they just banned all uses of `self`, allowing no exceptions because it' easier to implement this way.